# Using google script to manipulate data conditional formating and data validation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I was looking for already 3 days but nowhere found how to manipulate those two tools by google script.

I am interested in maiking script runned dynamic creation of worksheets and fast edditing of worksheets.

I need to alter those: data validation and conditional formating which are available normaly on tool bar.

Please help, give me the name of class that consists of those or the functions in google script with little information I will find rest.

Thanks in adavance
Tom

Answer (score 1):

Data validation can be set using [`Range.setDataValidation()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setDataValidation%28DataValidation%29). Unfortunately Apps Script doesn't support setting conditional formatting, but you can star [this feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=162) to get notified if/when it's added.

Answer (score 0):

The tools you are asking about appear to be in the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) class of the [Google Apps Script Spreadsheet API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/).  Note that the API calls deal with a range of cells at a time, although you can easily define a range that contains only one cell.

The question in its current form has nothing to do with Google App Engine, so consider taking that off the question tags.